# can i use the free assets from Unity Asset Store in a commercial game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

I just want to know if I can use the free assets from **Unity Asset Store** in a commercial game?
and maybe a simplified explanation of the asset store license .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have purchased an asset from the store, it becomes yours to do with as you like within your games and apps. You will be able to use them in your game for commercial use with no extra payments.

You can also use free assets in your game for commercial use. Using selected (non-restricted) Unity assets is fine, though be aware that many developers use Unity to create their games and most are aware of the assets we provide.

Unity "Restricted Assets" are subject to restrictions that others are not. These are only valid for personal and non-commercial use only. No other use is permitted, and these Unity assets must not be used in your commercial games.

You cannot duplicate an asset, or include it in an asset-type product.

Comment: when you say "it becomes yours to do with as you like within your games and apps."does it mean i can modify the assets ?

Comment: you can modify the assets for *YOUR* game but you cannot modify them and them sell them further on the store. so you can modify them to place in your game. but do not modify them to sell them on. but i see that you just want to use them for your game.

Comment: and can i use the assets on other platforms like ue4 or it has to be on unity ?

Comment: How to check that an asset is a restricted asset?

Comment: @EaswarChinraj it will explicitly say/tell you, most of the time if you have a free asset it will be yours to use but not sell on. if it is restricted most of the time the developer will tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the licence / rights for the asset you can use it. i do think UE4 give the licence with the asset/package but please do check if you have the right to modify it and use it.

this should be listed in its terms and conditions. if you do have the right to modify the asset then go ahead and use it in your program.

when you have them you can import them into Unity and use them as you want to.

Comment: what about using assets from unity asset store in the unreal engine ?

Comment: i think you can use them, but again not sell them forward. but using them should not be a problem.

Comment: ty bro yu the best !

Comment: of course man, you are welcome.